# ORA-01861 error when comparing dates sysdate

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT rc.ID AS ID_ROBOT_CARGA,
    ral.CIF AS CIF,
    rc.ID_CONTRATO AS REFERENCIA,
    CASE
        WHEN rc.RESPUESTA_INTERCHANGE = 1 THEN 'SI'
        WHEN rc.RESPUESTA_INTERCHANGE = 0 THEN 'NO'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS POPUP_INTERCHANGE
FROM
    ROBOT_CARGA rc
FULL JOIN ROBOT_ALTA_LINEA ral ON
    rc.ID = ral.ID_ROBOT_CARGA
WHERE
    rc.RESPUESTA_INTERCHANGE = 1
    AND rc.FECHA_RESPUESTA_INTERCHANGE > TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'day'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'); --FAILING HERE
```

So what i want it's taking the day of today in a WHERE condition but an error ORA-01861 it's been throwing i guess it's because of SYSDATE..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `FECHA_RESPUESTA_INTERCHANGE`  column's datatype? *Should be* `DATE`.

If so, then don't compare it to a string. `SYSDATE` is a function that returns `DATE`, so that would be just

```
and rc.FECHA_RESPUESTA_INTERCHANGE > trunc(sysdate)
```

---

Example which shows that it *works*:

Setting date format (you don't have to do that; it is irrelevant):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table robot_carga as
  2  select sysdate - 2 fecha_respuesta_interchange from dual;

Table created.
```

Query which comapres `fecha_respuesta_interchange` to `trunc(sysdate)`:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from robot_carga
  3  where fecha_respuesta_interchange < trunc(sysdate);

FECHA_RESPUESTA_INT
-------------------
08.01.2022 14:35:46

SQL>
```

See? No error.

Comment: It's not working for me like that, for example if i put this: AND rc.FECHA_RESPUESTA_INTERCHANGE > TO_DATE('2021-08-24','YYYY-mm-DD'); its working but not with trunc(sysdate)..

Comment: I updated the question with the DATE field FECHA_RESPUEST_AINTERCHANGE with his format

Comment: If it works with TO_DATE (your 1st comment), then it has to work with SYSDATE as well - datatypes are just the same. **Format** (your 2nd comment) doesn't matter; dates aren't stored in format you'd recognize (that's why we use e.g. TO_CHAR with desired format mask). What **matters** is that column's datatype (and you didn't specify it, yet).

Comment: It's type DATE.

Comment: OK, which means that what I suggested should work. You said it doesn't. What does it mean?

Comment: Have  a look at the edited answer which contains an example. I don't know what "fecha_respuesta_interchange" means. Is it supposed to be larger than sysdate? Besides, you still didn't say what "not working" means. I can't see your screen, I have no idea what it means.

Comment: can you add some data to get see what is column holding ,so we can compare with sysdate() to get needed results.